# Next.js params undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, parameters

I am trying to get the endpoint from a page in my Next.js application using the url parameters, but it keeps coming back `undefined` even though I can see the endpoint in the browser.

I have tried using `usePathname` from next/navigation, and that works but this requires usage in a Client Component, which I can't do because I need to use async/await for the component because it is fetching data from a database.

In `app/category/[id]/page.tsx`:

```
const CategoryPage = async (props: Props, { params }) => {
  ...
  let notes = await getNotes(params.id);
}
```

The `getNotes` function is a request function in a utils folder which fetches my api route at `app/api/[id]/route.ts`.

I have also tried changing the file structure for the api route to include "category" like this: `app/api/category/[id]/route.ts`, but this had no effect.

I start the app with `npm run dev`. When I try to access the category page, the expected path shows in the browser, but it instead loads the error page that says `params` is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Next.js - Dynamic Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#example):

```
const CategoryPage = async ({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) => {
  // ...
  let notes = await getNotes(params.id);
  // ...
}
```

`params` would be provided in the first function argument.